# lower bound of the difference between two numbers

Tags: real-analysis

There are two real numbers $x_1$ and $x_2$, and $x_1$ is bounded $[ay, by]$ and $x_2$ is bounded by $[cy, dy]$ where $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ are all positive numbers. Is there a lower bound for the difference between the numbers, i.e., $|x_1 - x_2|$. Intuitively the lower bound is $my$ where $m$ is a positive number because the bounds shrink as $y$ approaches zero, but I do not know how to prove. 
More specifically, $x_1$ is the Frobenius norm of $AB$; $x_2$ is the Frobenius norm of $BC$; and $C$ is a similarity transformed matrix of $A$; a = 1 over 2-norm of inverse $A$; b = Frobenius norm of $A$; $c$ = 1 over 2-norm of inverse $C$; d = Frobenius norm of $C$

Comment: As you wrote here $0$ is the sharpest lower bound. It is the case when $[ay,by] \cap[cy,dy] \neq \emptyset$.

Comment: What is $y$?  Are the italic and Roman ones the same?

Comment: any difference between two real number must be nonnegative. Therefore 0 lower bound is too obvious.

Comment: y is some number.

Comment: x_1 is the Frobenius norm of A*B; x_2 is the Frobenius norm of B*C; and C is a similarity transformed matrix of A; a = 1 over 2-norm of inverse A; b = Frobenius norm of A; c = 1 over 2-norm of inverse C; d = Frobenius norm of C

Answer (score 1):

WLOG assume $ay<cy$. (You can just switch the two numbers if this is not the case) Then if $cy<by$, the minimum difference is zero. Otherwise, the minimum difference is $cy-by$, because that is when you choose $x_1$ at is maximum, and $x_2$ at its minimum.

Comment: The information is unknown for a general case.

Comment: What information?

Comment: In general, I do not have any information on magnitudes of $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ except $a$ < $b$ and $c$ < $d$

Comment: You can prove using cases, exactly the way I did it to show that the minimum difference approaches zero when y does. In my answer, both cases, lim cy-by and lim 0 approach zero when y approaches zero

Answer (score 0):

You can write
$$ay\le x_1\le by$$
and 
$$-dy\le -x_2\le -cy$$
so
$$ay-dy\le x_1-x_2\le by-cy$$

Comment: This works only if $x_1 > x_2$

Comment: The other case can be solved analoguosly

Comment: You are right, but (b-c) may be smaller than (a-d).

Comment: Yes in this case we have the condition $$ay-dy<by-cy$$

Comment: Thanks, but we do not know which one is larger in general. So, my question is if the difference |x_1 - x_2| has a lower bound which can be expressed in terms of y.

Comment: Say a = 1, b = 3, c = 2, d = 4. The minimum is 0, but neither one of your cases gives that answer.